# JQuery .bind() correct format

Tags: jquery, bind, wymeditor

I have this code -

```
jQuery('.wymeditor').wymeditor( {
    html: '<p>Hello, World!<\/p>',
    postInit: function(wym) {
         var html = "<li class='wym_tools_newbutton'>"
                 + "<a name='NewButton' href='#'"
                 + " style='background-image:"
                 + " url(js/wymeditor/img/media.png);'"
                 + " title='Insert an image' >"
                 + "</a></li>";
       jQuery(wym._box).find(wym._options.toolsSelector + wym._options.toolsListSelector).append(html);
       jQuery(wym._box).find('li.wym_tools_newbutton a').click(function() {

       jQuery('#modal').show().css( { 'left': (winW-980)/2+'px', 'top': '100px' } ).load('admin_list_media.php');

                jQuery('.imgname').bind('change',function(){

                alert('123');

                var InsertImg = '#'+jQuery(this).attr('id');

                wym.insert('<img src="uploads/'+jQuery(InsertImg).val()+'" />');

                jQuery('#modal').empty().hide();

             });
            return(false);
            } );
            }
        } );
```

which adds a new button to a wym editor.  This opens a modal which contains images, the idea is to select an image and insert into the wym editor.  Works if i use `jQuery('.imgname').live('change',function(){ ...` but not if I use `jQuery('.imgname').bind('change',function(){` problem is I have to use .bind() because the change event handler gets bound every time the modal opens and so I dupliacte image inserts each time I was told to replace .live() with .bind() but it doesn't work (OK in my code).  Suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by moving the insert outside of the onchange section

Answer (score 1):

First of all: why don't you use `live` but do it *once* when your page loads? You say "I have to use `bind` because the event handler gets bound every time..." but that sounds confusing. The event handler gets bound every time *because* you use `bind`, not the other way around.

Failing that, a quick and dirty solution would be:

```
$(".imgname").unbind("change").bind("change", function () {
    // ...
});
```

A much better solution (again, without `live`) would be the [`hasEventListener`](https://github.com/sebastien-p/jquery.hasEventListener) plugin. Read the documentation, or play with its [sandbox on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastienp/eHGqB/).